# Fetchmail with local Postfix on Home-Server

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, dovecot, fetchmail

a small question...
I have a fully configured postfix server which have a few domains, few users, and much more.

Then I have a smart host which receives all mails and send all mails.
For example 1and1.com or some hoster like that.

The HomeServer postfix has this hosting as SmartHost (= RelayHost) configured. So that all outgoing mails would be send via this hosting.

For incoming mails I have a external POP3 account for this hosting. It's like catch-all@example.org.

Via fetchmail I want to retrieve all mails from the catch all and deliver VIA POSTFIX to local users. (Or maybe with dovecot directly!?)

So the POP3 account contains a mail like:
"FROM: noreply@stackexchange.com\n
RCPT TO: person@example.org"

The fetchmail should retrieve this mail and "send"/forward/save the mail in the inbox of user with mail address "person@example.org".

Configuration of fetchmail:

```
set daemon        300                # Pool every 5 minutes
set syslog                        # log through syslog facility
set postmaster  root

set no bouncemail                # avoid loss on 4xx errors
defaults:
timeout 300
antispam -1
batchlimit 100

poll pop.1and1.com protocol POP3 user "*@example.org" there with password "Passw0rd!" ssl fetchall
```

And the log said:

```
Nov 16 18:20:23 core fetchmail[61595]: 3 Messages for *@example.org on pop.1and1.com (21260 Bytes).
Nov 16 18:20:23 core fetchmail[61595]: Message *@example.org@pop.1and1.com:1 of 3 (3907 Bytes) deleted
Nov 16 18:20:23 core postfix/local[56731]: 294BE15C0866: to=<fetchmail@localhost>, relay=local, delay=0.42, delays=0.27/0/0/0.15, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Nov 16 18:20:23 core fetchmail[61595]: Message *@example.org@pop.1and1.com:2 of 3 (4516 Bytes) deleted
Nov 16 18:20:23 core postfix/local[56575]: 7496F15C0876: to=<fetchmail@localhost>, relay=local, delay=0.3, delays=0.27/0/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Nov 16 18:20:23 core fetchmail[61595]: Message *@example.org@pop.1and1.com:3 of 3 (12837 Bytes) deleted
Nov 16 18:20:24 core postfix/local[56731]: C11DC15C0866: to=<fetchmail@localhost>, relay=local, delay=0.24, delays=0.2/0/0/0.04, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
```

Thanks in Advance for any idea's!

Answer (score 2):

Fixed with this.

```
poll pop.1and1.com
  protocol POP3
  envelope "Delivered-To:"
  localdomains example.org
  user "*@example.org" there
  with password "Passw0rd!"
  is * here
  smtpaddress localhost
  ssl
  fetchall
```

Then the postfix receive all mails and handles the correct mailbox. (Its funny: You can redirect fetched mails to internet :D :D)

But thanks @Lambert for your Idea. I read about mda and dont know if it's usefull and the "is local-user here" not worked, too.

Comment: You did not try the `local-user` literally did you? You need the actual name of the local user where you want to deliver the mails to... Nevertheless, thanks for posting your working solution, it will help other people.

Comment: I tested it! The problem is that the recipient is dynamic. So i have no "local-user" or "johndoe" for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can instruct `fetchmail` which is the remote user and which is the local user by:

```
poll pop.1and1.com protocol POP3:
    user "myuser@example.org" there with password "Passw0rd!" ssl fetchall
    is local-user here
```

It is also possible to use another mda using:

```
poll pop.1and1.com protocol POP3:
    user "myuser@example.org" there with password "Passw0rd!" ssl fetchall
    is local-user here and wants mda /path/to/mda
```